# How does F# map2 iter2 ||> work with Vector?

Tags: f#, dictionary, vector, geometry, iteration

Input two arrays of Vector x,y pair by x,y pair
and find the function of the two x,y pairs
output new array ...?

```
    let v1 = [|for x, y in [3.,3.; 5.,5.; 1.,1.] -> Vector(x, y)|];;
    let v2 = [|for x, y in [1.,1.; 2.,2.; 4.,4.] -> Vector(x, y)|];;

    let data8 v1 v2 = Array.map2 (fun x y -> Vector.CrossProduct) v1 v2
```

val v1 : Vector [] = [|3,3; 5,5; 1,1|]

val v2 : Vector [] = [|1,1; 2,2; 4,4|]

val data8 : 'a [] -> 'b [] -> (Vector * Vector -> float) []

> data8 v1 v2;;
>   val it : (Vector * Vector -> float) [] =
>     [|; ; |]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://fpish.net/topic/Some/0/73895

> You forgot to pass the arguments to Vector.CrossProduct:
>
> ```
> let data8 v1 v2 = Array.map2 (fun x y -> Vector.CrossProduct(x, y)) v1 v2
> ```

Comment: Can you simply pass Vector.CrossProduct directly?

Comment: No, because ``CrossProduct`` is a method which receives two arguments, not a curried function. If it were a curried function, then the syntax would be: ``Array.map2 Vector.CrossProduct v1 v2``

Comment: Thanks, I figured I missed something. Remembering the distinction between (a,b)->c vs a->b->c is always important.

Comment: Thanks Ramon and Guvnte. I'd been looking at:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.crossproduct.aspx    let v1 = [|for x, y in [20.,30.; 5.,5.; 1.,1.] -> Vector(x, y)|];;
    let v2 = [|for x, y in [45.,70.; 2.,2.; 4.,4.] -> Vector(x, y)|];;

    let data8 v1 v2 = Array.map2 (fun x y -> Vector.CrossProduct(x, y)) v1 v2  
> data8 v1 v2;;  
val it : float [] = [|50.0; 0.0; 0.0|]

Comment: Next I'd like to know if this makes any sense, and how do I go about implementing it...    <pre> <code>let data8 v1 v2 = Array.Parallel.map2 (fun x y -> Vector.CrossProduct(x, y)) v1 v2

Comment: See http://fpish.net/topic/Some/0/73895 for full response, the comment box here is just too tiny.